Bash Script Not Copying SSH Keys to Remote Servers in EC2 User Data
I'm using Terraform to automate the setup of an EC2 instance using a bash script provided in the user data. The script is supposed to install some packages, generate SSH keys, and copy them to two remote servers using ssh-copy-id. Everything works fine, except the part where the script copies the SSH keys to the remote servers.
Here's the relevant part of my script:
SERVERS=("server1" "server2")

for SERVER in "$${SERVERS[@]}"
do
    sudo -u ${USER} /usr/bin/sshpass -p ${PASSWORD} ssh-copy-id -f -i /home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ${USER}@$SERVER
done


I'm installing sshpass and ssh-copy-id before this part of the script.
When I check the logs (/var/log/cloud-init-output.log), I see the following message:
/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of keys to be installed: '/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'

The keys are not actually copied to the remote servers.
when I run this part of the script manually after the instance is launched, it works perfectly and the keys are copied successfully.
I've checked that the variables ${USER} and ${PASSWORD} are correctly set, and there are no errors in the logs.
How can I troubleshoot or fix this issue?
I forgot to mention I'm using terraform. So without the additional $ it conflicts with the shell script and the additional $ is a workaround. And either way even if it was a mistake it should return an error similar to unable to resolve hostname.

"$${SERVERS[@]}" has one dollar sign to much.

yea, I forgot to mention I'm using terraform. So without the additional $ it conflicts with the shell script and the additional $ is a workaround. And either way even if it was a mistake it should return an error similar to unable to resolve hostname.

I’m voting to close this question because poster did not use shellcheck as explicitly stated in the bash tag description. Using shellcheck would have resolved the poster's issue as it would have revealed typos and missing double quotes.

There are, I believe, better ways to install SSH keys with Terraform than simply running ssh-copy-id after the machine has been created and provisioned. Fixing the bash script would be more of a hack than a proper solution in that case.

@Typewriter Ok, I understand the usage of $$ (it's like make). But isn't there a dollar sign missing in front of $SERVER? -> ${USER}@$$SERVER

To troubelshoot add set -x to your script this will print complete commands in the log.
Another thing don't use sudo in user data script as scripts run as root so the command should be like this (I added full path) :
/usr/bin/sshpass -p ${PASSWORD} ssh-copy-id -f -i /home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ${USER}@$SERVER:/home/${USER}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

